# having difficulty drawing multiple polygons on a canvas. kindly have a look

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, polygon

I want to draw multiple polygons on a canvas whose background is an image. I load the polygon points from a json file and store it to an array, then iterate through the array to draw the polygons. but so far only the first polygon is being drawn no matter what, spent three days on this issue. please have a look and help me move on to the next steps of my project. thank you!

for example, a json below:

```
var jsonf = {
      "shapes": [
        {
          "line_color": [0, 255, 255, 255], 
          "points": [[217, 44], [210, 43], [208, 35], [209, 28], [215, 25], [219, 31], [219, 39]], 
          "fill_color": [0, 0, 0, 128], 
          "label": "Haemorrhages-Resized"
        }, 
        {
          "line_color": [0, 255, 255, 255], 
          "points": [[384, 60], [378, 56], [378, 48], [384, 45], [388, 51], [385, 58]], 
          "fill_color": [0, 0, 0, 128], 
          "label": "Haemorrhages-Resized"
        }
      ]
    }
```

this json may have many "shapes" entries, I just show two of them here for the brevity!

now, extracting points from the json and storing it to 'points' array and use it to draw polygons, code below:

```
var points = [];

var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);

for (var i=0; i<jsonf.shapes.length; i++) {

   for (var j=0; j<jsonf.shapes[i].points.length; j++) {
     points.push({x: jsonf.shapes[i].points[j][0], y: jsonf.shapes[i].points[j][1]});
   }

   ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 128)';
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 255)';
   ctx.lineWidth= 1;

   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
   for(var index=1; index<points.length; index++) {
     ctx.lineTo(points[index].x, points[index].y);
   }

   ctx.closePath();
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stroke();

   points = [];
}
```

what am I missing? Thank you!

Comment: Pasted your code and it works on the spot: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/egL42rxz/ Note that a canvas without stated dimensions is 300x150 internally, so the second polygon might be off-canvas for you. (Also, the alpha channel is stated as 0.0 - 1.0, not 0 - 255).

Comment: Your points are very near one of each other, almost overlapping. All you get is a cluster of points. Maybe you need to recalculate the values for the coordinates.

Comment: surprisingly, your jsfiddle works, but it still doesn't show any other polygons on my side : (@ChrisG

Comment: @enxaneta no, those are the coordinates I want, the above jsfiddle by Chris G works, but not working on my side

Comment: @ChrisG the size of my canvas is 525 x 525 on my side, still no change

Comment: well in that case the issue is somewhere else, what does your console say?

Comment: @techKid-Rinshad You need to post a [mcve] that reproduces the problem or we cannot help you.